# How to Apply Filters in DataView(To hide top 5 rows, to hide last 10 rows)

Tags: asp.net, filter, dataview

*Hi I want to hide top 5 rows/top 20/bottom 5...etc. How to filter in DataView. Please someone help me out to resolve this. Thanks in advance. *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linq.Check out below linq query.

```
var result= dataView.ToTable().AsEnumerable().OrderBy(r => r["ID"]).Skip(5).ToList();
```

For more information check out following msdn link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669073(v=vs.110).aspx